# create touch ripples unconstrained by parent view

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have an `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` in a `RelativeLayout`. I get touch ripples, but they are constrained by the relative layout. Is there a simple way to have the ripples overflow the parent? (this is using appcompat 22.1.1)

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkbox"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*update* removed the background on the RelativeLayout, it was irrelevant to the actual issue at hand. The behavior is the same.

Comment: @Booger I figured it wasn't that valuable, as it's pretty much the simplest version of what I stated in the question.. but I have now added it. Thanks for looking.

Comment: The ripple is drawn on the first parent which doesn't have a null background. So if the relative layout has no background its parent must have. `@android:color/transparent` may be such background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">
```

(note the 'Borderless' suffix)

EDIT 1:

Another idea is to allow the parent view group to override its [children's clipping](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipChildren(boolean)): android:clipChildren="false" (android:clipToPadding="false")

Comment: tried that on both the relativelayout and the checkbox and it didn't seem to change behavior of either. could be because I'm manually inflating this layout and adding it to a view hierarchy... not sure yet.

Comment: Hmm, I see... My bad. Have you tried android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"?

Comment: finally got around to revisiting this bug and you had it right. if you update your answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

Put the

> android:background="?selectableItemBackground"

attribute on your

> AppCompatCheckBox

, instead of the bounding

> RelativeLayout

.

Comment: This is a row that is touchable with ripples separate from the checkbox ripples.

Comment: Also, I am seeing ripples on both the row and the checkbox, I just would like the checkbox ripples to not stop at the edge of the RelativeLayout